# x509: certificate signed by unknown authority in kuberenetes redhat 8

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openssl, x509certificate, ca

I am trying to deploy image from local-docker-registry it showing the error like this

```
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   
    Image:          local-docker-registry:5001/nginx
    Image ID:       
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       ErrImagePull
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-n7t6w (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-n7t6w:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                 ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  36m                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/nginx to cs9-master3
  Normal   Pulling    35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Pulling image "local-docker-registry:5001/nginx"
  Warning  Failed     35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Failed to pull image "local-docker-registry:5001/nginx": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to pull and unpack image "local-docker-registry:5001/nginx:latest": failed to resolve reference "local-docker-registry:5001/nginx:latest": failed to do request: Head "https://local-docker-registry:5001/v2/nginx/manifests/latest": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
  Warning  Failed     35m (x4 over 36m)    kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed     35m (x6 over 36m)    kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff    93s (x152 over 36m)  kubelet            Back-off pulling image "local-docker-registry:5001/nginx"
```

I generated certificate from this cmd
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -days 365 -nodes -sha256 -keyout /root/certs/domain.key -out /root/certs/domain.crt -subj "/CN=local-docker-registry" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:local-docker-registry"`

Then I copied the domain.crt certificate to /etc/docker/certs.d/local-docker-registry:5001
and same in docker client machines
I able to push and pull and login to the local-docker-registry manually but while deploying I am facing this error I don't know where I missing.

Give the correct way to generate the certificate to resovle the problem